# Firebase Write Rule for Item with nested approved users

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a realtime database with users and teams. Each team has a list of approved users under settings.. I want to create a rule so only approved users can write to their team...

something like:

[image: my database json]

[image: Firebase RUles]

Comment: Do you want to do this using only rules or do you mind trying Firebase Custom Claims? They are more ideal for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend Custom Claims because they are very limited in space.

You can write the rule very easy using the `exists` clause:

```json
 "teams": {
   "$team_id" : {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "auth != null && root.child('teams/'+$team_id+'/settings/approvedUsers/'+auth.uid).exists()"
      }
}
```

This rule will also deny a creation if there is no user on that path. You can then create the team from the backend or mark some users as admins or if anyone can create a team you can add a clause that checks if there is any data before and if not the rule befor should not get used. Something like this:

```json
 "teams": {
   "$team_id" : {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "!data.exists() || (auth != null && root.child('teams/'+$team_id+'/settings/approvedUsers/'+auth.uid).exists())"
      }
}
```

Here we check if the team already exists and if not anyone can create it. If it exist only users under approvedUsers can change it. That way the first user creating the team can create it. But don't forget that he needs to add himself to approvedUsers.

If you are working with emails for users that are not already in the system you could use the email instead of an uid as key and just set the value of the key to `true`. Just make sure te remove all chars that are not allowed as key from the email withe something like:

```js
email.replace('.','')
```

And also do the same in the rules like:

```js
"teams": {
   "$team_id" : {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "auth != null && root.child('teams/'+$team_id+'/settings/approvedUsers/'+auth.token.email.replace('.','')).exists()"
      }
}
```

The databse would then look like:

```js
teams
  teamID1
    approvedUsers
       email1@test.com: true
       email2@test.com: true
  teamID2
    approvedUsers
       email1@test.com: true
       email3@test.com: true
```

Comment: This is really close.... my problem is If I'm the admin of a team, I'm trying to add approved users before they've even logged in..  by adding their email addresses to the approvedUsers area. .(which doesn't generate the correct UID if the intended user has never been in the system) so there UID doesn't seem to work.. is there some way to do '+auth.uid).exists())" but with an email address instead?  I have the user's email stored in the user > uid > email, below nickName normally.  (not show in my screenshot) . can I compare that email with email in settings/approvedUsers?

Comment: You can get the auth email in the rules with `auth.token.email` but the problem here would the that the `uid` in the path `teams/$team_id/approvedUsers` is not a user uid and you need to know the uid for the exists clause path. I'm not familiar enough with your registration workflow and database strukture to gie a stright solution for this but maybe you can use this infor for one. If you have any further questions et me know.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a solution that would use the email as `approvedUsers` key.